# Using "find_theorems" in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I want to find theorems. I have read the section on `find_theorems` in the [Isabelle/Isar reference manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf):

> **find_theorems** *criteria*
>
> Retrieves facts from the theory or proof context matching all of given search
>   criteria. The criterion *`name: p`* selects all theorems whose fully qualified
>   name matches pattern *p*, which may contain "`*`" wildcards. The criteria *`intro`*,
>   *`elim`*, and *`dest`* select theorems that match the current goal as introduction,
>   elimination or destruction rules, respectively.  The criterion *`solves`* returns
>   all rules that would directly solve the current goal. The criterion *`simp: t`*
>   selects all rewrite rules whose left-hand side matches the given term. The
>   criterion term *t* selects all theorems that contain the pattern *t* -- as usual,
>   patterns may contain occurrences of the dummy "`_`" , schematic variables, and
>   type constraints.
>
> Criteria can be preceded by "`-`" to select theorems that do not match.  Note
>   that giving the empty list of criteria yields all currently known facts. An
>   optional limit for the number of printed facts may be given; the default is 40.
>   By default, duplicates are removed from the search result. Use *`with_dups`* to
>   display duplicates.

As far as I understand, `find_theorems` is used in the find window of Isabelle/jEdit. The above does not help me finding relevant theorems for the following situation (Lambda is a theory of the [Nominal Isabelle](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/nominal/) extension. The tarball is [here](http://www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Publications/Nominal2-2013-2.tgz)):

```
theory First
imports Lambda

begin

theorem "Lam [x].(Lam [y].(App (Var x)(Var y))) = Lam [y].(Lam [x].(App (Var y)(Var x)))"
```

When I try the search expression `Lam` Isabelle/jedit says

```
Inner syntax error: unexpected end of input
Failed to parse term
```

How can I make it look for all the theorems that contain the constant `Lam`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Lam` like the ordinary lambda (`%`) is not a term on its own, you should add the remaining parts to get a proper term, which may contain wildcards. In your example, I would perform

```
find_theorems "Lam [_]. _"
```

which gives lots of answers.

Answer (score 3):

Typically this happens whenever special syntax was defined for some constant. But there is (almost) always an underlying ("raw") *constant*. To find out which constant provides the `Lam [_]. _` syntax. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click `Lam` (inside a proper term) within Isabelle/jEdit. This will jump to the definition of the underlying constant.

For `Lam` there is the additional complication that the binder syntax uses exactly the same string as the underlying constant, namely `Lam`, as can be seen at the place of definition:

```
nominal_datatype lam =
  Var "name"
| App "lam" "lam"
| Lam x::"name" l::"lam"  binds x in l ("Lam [_]. _" [100, 100] 100)
```

In such cases you can use the *long name* of the constant by prefixing it with the theory name, i.e., `Lambda.Lam`.

**Note:** The same works for binders like `ALL x. P x` (with underlying constant `All`), but not for the built-in `%x. x`.